# rails3 devise shared links partial i18n

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, rails-i18n

Cannot figure out how to render YML files for views/devise/shared/_links. No traditional file picks anything up.

Akita here actually write a new file
https://github.com/akitaonrails/Rails-3-I18n-Demonstration/tree/master/config/locales
devise.views.en.yml
which is news to me.

So devise.language-code.yml is only for error messages.  form field labels go under activerecord.user.  What about all these other labels?  Do we need to create a view file for that?  If so, how come there does not appear to be translation files on github?

which begets a larger question... what else is there to know regarding i18n files for devise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generate the devise-views (if you haven't already), and you will see, that no I18n-magic is going on by default in `views/devise/shared/_links`. Just put in your own translations, which you can store wherever you want, and you should be fine.

I am using Devise in a medium sized application with two different locales and I don't have any problems so far.

Comment: "which you can store wherever you want".  Tried that, but it's not clear how the nesting may/could occur.  For if controller_name != 'sessions' or registrations, activerecord/attributes/user/t_string works. But for controller_name != 'passwords' that heierarchy is not picking up.

Comment: Why do you need a view hierarchy? Just put the view path into your translation helper, like `t('devise.shared.forgot_password')` and then you add this nesting to your `devise.<locale>.yml`-files

Comment: OK. that did work.  Odd, because  activerecord/attributes/user/ worked for the two first cases I mentioned. Thanks for the pointer

Answer (score 2):

shared links of devise doesn't use localization keys by default
seems your project have custom view override of shared/_links view
look to devise.views.pt-BR.yml at your source and copy necessary  keys to devise.en.yml (or whatever locale you need)

for additional translations add this to your Gemfile

```
gem 'devise-i18n'
```

Comment: Have the gem. tried exactly that approach with Akita's strings and brought it into devise.lang_code.yml and zilch.